# Как поставить случайный выбор в Python для выражений не касательно чисел?

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Как поставить случайный выбор в Python для выражений не касательно чисел?
например:

```
import random 
number = random.randint (1 , 5)
```

это ведь касательно в частности целого числа?
а вот если я бы хотел вместо чисел поставить слова, то какое выражение вместo

```
randint
```

должно быть?

Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте функцию [choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
import random
print(random.choice(['Hello', 'World', '!']))
```

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно выбрать не 1 элемент а к примеру 3:

```
In [7]: import random

In [8]: random.sample(['hello', 'world', 'python', 'Rossym'], 3)
Out[8]: ['python', 'world', 'hello']
```